# ASP.NET web page to device connect to server's USB (COM) port

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, usb, arduino

I am working on a way to send commands to an Arduino board from a web site. The Arduino board is connected to the computer via a USB port (a COM port).

I have managed to connect and control the board using a VB.NET program. I also wrote a VB.NET class that can instantiate a COM connection and send and receive messages.

My next step is to basically create a program that will act as a proxy between my web server (IIS 7 running on Windows Vista) and the Arduino board. When a user gets to my ASP.NET page, the page will then send a command to the proxy to open the COM connection. When the connection is open and ready then I can send commands to the proxy. In turn, the proxy will send these commands to the board and listen for the responses it receives from the board. The proxy will then pass these messages back to the ASP.NET page.

I have several questions I hope the group can help me answer...

1. Am I in the right direction with this approach? Are there easier or more efficient ways of doing this?
2. The main issue I see occurring is that if a second user opens the web page and tries to open the COM port, there will be an error. Will this cause the first connection to fail? I guess I can first check if the port is already in use and give the second user a message.
3. Are there any other potential challenges I am missing or not seeing?

Comment: Quick Update: I know that i can now connect to the serial port directly from asp.net. However, i do not want to be opening and closing the connection each time i post the page. since the http is stateless, i cannot direlcty keep a serial connection open via http alone. I would like to have the connection opened while the user session is on, or when the user logs out or sends a close command. Thank you!

Comment: it appears that i have found a possible solution.. simply putting the object i use to connect to my board in a session variable, and then refering to the session var by CTypeing it appears to do the trick! A simple solution to what i thought was going to be a complicated problem. No need for the proxy app... However, i would like to hear what other solutions may be on experts' minds!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing the connecting object in the [`HttpSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx), store it in the [`HttpApplicationState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx) so that it is accessible to all users.

You'll need to be careful to synchronize access to the COM port to avoid the serial communication initiated by individual HTTP requests from getting mixed up and confusing the Arduino.

Comment: Thank you for yout reply. I think i figured it out. The thing is that i really don't want too many users to access this. It is intended to be an internal app that only one person needs to use. I've made the application require authentication. I will, however, plpay with the application state to see if this makes a difference. Thanks again!